# could not load image permission denied

Tags: 18.04, permissions, rar

I am very new to Ubuntu. I have shifted from Windows 10. Now when I want to open some *.rar* files it gives error permission denied. pleas help

[image: Error Screenshot]

[Permissions tab in properies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX27j.png)

Comment: First try: right click on file, select `properties` then see the `permissions` tab

Comment: I have all read/write permission but still this error is there

Comment: What are permissions of the directory where the file is located?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get this permission issue when trying to unrar a file into /media/?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461410/why-do-i-get-this-permission-issue-when-trying-to-unrar-a-file-into-media)